# PHP : Whats is a different between self:: and class_name::?

Tags: php

I have a class like this :
I would like to know what the differences between following commands, which one is better?

```
Class foo
{
    function test()
    {
        return false;
    }
    function test2()
    {
        return self::test();
    }
    function test3()
    {
        return foo::test();
    }
    static function test4()
    {
        return false;
    }
    function test5()
    {
        return self::test4();
    }
    function test6()
    {
        return static::test4();
    }

}
```

1 - Whats is a different between `self::test();` and `foo::test();` ?
2 - Whats is a different between `self::test4();` and `static::test4();` ?
Please explain??

Comment: "which one is better?" is not the right question to ask; the answer is almost certainly "it depends".

Comment: Though, in the first case, `$this->test()` would be the typical approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1 - Whats is a different between self::test(); and foo::test(); ?

It's the same, if used inside the class scope, `self::` will be better, you don't have to change the code when you change the class name.

> 2 - Whats is a different between self::test4(); and static::test4(); ?

`static::test4()` is implemented from php 5.3 as the **[Late Static Bindings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)** feather, which can be used to reference the called class in a context of static inheritance.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Nope, that's what `static::` will do but not `self::`.

Answer (score 1):

simply: **self** - is referencing the class you are in. while **class_name** could call a class method's outside of the class itself.

i.e - when you want to call test6 outside of 'foo' - you can't call it by 'self', you have to call it by 'foo::'.

**which one is better?**

As I explained. when writing inside the class it self, use 'self' - it's just 'best practice'.

Answer (score 0):

#### Whats is a different between self::test(); and foo::test(); ?

```
function test2()
{
    return self::test();
}

function test3()
{
    return foo::test();
}
```

They both work in the same way, but  when you want to rename your class; `self` would still point to the correct class, but `foo` would have to be renamed.

Even better would be to use `$this->test()`.

#### Whats is a different between self::test4(); and static::test4(); ?

```
function test5()
{
    return self::test4();
}
function test6()
{
    return static::test4();
}
```

The latter applies "late static binding" and so there will be a difference when this class is extended, e.g.:

```
class bar extends foo
{
    function test4() { return true; }
}

$b = new bar;
```

Then when `$b->test6()` is called it will return `true`.